# Efficiently counting elements in a very large XML doc using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a very large (1.8GB) XML document. I'd like to simply find the number of elements with the tag `<Product>`.

I've got this far:

```
context = etree.iterparse('./test.xml', tag='Product')
num_elems = 0
for event, elem in context:
    num_elems += 1
print num_elems
```

It works, but is there a faster way of doing it?

Comment: I think you're on the right track it's just that you have a large xml file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324214/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-parse-large-xml-docs-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this works, I take it that memory use is not an issue (`iterparse` *will* build a tree of the entire file in memory unless you prune it while iterating over the elements). In that case, save yourself the trouble of iterating and counting in Python and let LXML/`libxml` handle that in C:

```
tree = etree.parse("./test.xml")
num_elems = tree.xpath("count(//Product)")    # note: returns a float
```

Comment: Is this a better way, than the following code:
`tree = etree.parse("./test.xml"); products = tree.findall("Product"); num_elems = len(products) if products is not None else None`?