# Fastest way to parse XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to find the qickest way to parse sensor data from a smartphone for a realtime application. The Format looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<NodeId>0</NodeId>
<Accelerometer>
    <Accelerometer1>-.1875240802764893</Accelerometer1>
    <Accelerometer2>4.6734819412231445</Accelerometer2>
    <Accelerometer3>8.312667846679688</Accelerometer3>
</Accelerometer>
<Gyroscope>
    <Gyroscope1>-0.10551923513412476</Gyroscope1>
    <Gyroscope2>0.009592439979314804</Gyroscope2>
    <Gyroscope3>0.019185146316885948</Gyroscope3>
</Gyroscope>
<Gravity>
    <Gravity1>-1.2976515293121338</Gravity1>
    <Gravity2>3.672762393951416</Gravity2>
    <Gravity3>9.003327369689941</Gravity3>
</Gravity>
<TimeStamp>1377767599250</TimeStamp>
```

The available sensor data might change depending on the phone. But once the connection is established the structure of the packages won't change, so maybe parts of the parsing could be skipped.

Comment: A general suggestion - depending on how fast your I/O is (are you fetching the data over a slow connection?) and how big the file is it may make sense to parse the data as you're transmitting it, i.e. use a SAX parser and feed it the chunks of markup as you receive it.

Comment: Many of the key considerations in selecting a parser are about memory efficiency, as opposed to time efficiency. Your question doesn't speak to that, and the accepted answer only speaks to DOM-style solutions, which inherently are somewhat memory-inefficient.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, ...a parser implementing the SAX API was the old model for streaming, but I'd actually go with lxml.iterparse these days -- still fast and memory-efficient, but much less painful to work with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If parsing speed is a key factor for you, consider using [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm) or [lxml](http://lxml.de).

There are definitely more options out there, see these threads:

- [What is the fastest way to parse large XML docs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324214/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-parse-large-xml-docs-in-python)
- [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)
- [High-performance XML parsing in Python with lxml](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/)