# Parse multiple large XML files and write to CSV

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, csv

I have around 1000 XML files each of 250 MB size. I need to extract some data from them and write to CSV. **There cannot not be any duplicate entries.**

I have a system with 4GB RAM and an AMD A8 processor.

I have already gone through some previous posts here but they don't seem to answer my problem.

I have already written the code in Python and tested it on a sample XML and it worked well.

However it was very slow (almost 15 mins for each file) when I used it on all files and had to terminate the process midway.

What can be an optimal solution to speed up the process?

Here's the code

```
path='data/*.xml'
t=[]
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print('Parsing ',fname)
    tree=ET.parse(fname)
    root=tree.getroot()
    x=root.findall('//Article/AuthorList//Author')
    for child in x:
        try:
            lastName=child.find('LastName').text
        except AttributeError:
            lastName=''
        try:
            foreName=child.find('ForeName').text
        except AttributeError:
            foreName=''
        t.append((lastName,foreName))
    print('Parsed ',fname)

t=set(t)
```

I want the fastest method to get the entries **without any duplicate values**.
(Maybe storing in some DB instead of variable t, Will storing each entry in DB speed up due to more free RAM ?- whatever be the method I need direction towards it)

Comment: and for speed problem check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507481/fastest-way-to-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: If you want unique entries then use a set or dict instead of a list. Have you tried lxml as it may be faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing the results to a Python list, create a database table with a `UNIQUE` constraint, and write all the results to that table. Once all the writing has been done, dump the DB table as a csv.

If you don't want to have any additional dependencies for writing to the DB, I suggest you use `sqlite3`, as it comes right out of the box with any recent Python installation.

Here's some code to get started:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('large_xml.db')  # db will be created
cur = conn.cursor()
crt = "CREATE TABLE foo(fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), UNIQUE(fname, lname))"
cur.execute(crt)
conn.commit()

path='data/*.xml'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print('Parsing ',fname)
    tree=ET.parse(fname)
    root=tree.getroot()
    x=root.findall('//Article/AuthorList//Author')
    count = 0
    for child in x:
        try:
            lastName=child.find('LastName').text
        except AttributeError:
            lastName=''
        try:
            foreName=child.find('ForeName').text
        except AttributeError:
            foreName=''
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo(fname, lname) VALUES(?, ?)", (foreName, lastName))
        count += 1
        if count > 3000:  # commit every 3000 entries, you can tune this
            count = 0
            conn.commit()

    print('Parsed ',fname)
```

After the database is populated, dump it to csv as follows:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv large_xml.db "select * from foo;" > dump.csv
```

Also, experiment with faster parsing ways.
Furthermore, if the `.text` attribute is available most of the times, 
following will perhaps be faster than exception handling:

```
lastName = getattr(child.find('LastName'), 'text', '')
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this one out and revert back in comment. Let's hope it works.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty Perhaps some of the starter code above might help.

Comment: this code is inserting duplicate entries into the table. I clearly mentioned that I do not want any duplicate entries.. @Sam

Comment: I want lastName, foreName together to be UNIQUE attribute and not separately. That is Michael, S and Michael, S will be treated same while Michael, K and Michael, S will be treated different. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I __want__ a holiday. It doesn’t seem like you are actually *trying* to solve your own problem - what have you _done_ to solve it?

Comment: Speed is obviously better because it's just parsing and pushing into the DB.

Comment: But my main point was not having duplicate entries. INSERT OR IGNORE INTO isn't giving that. I checked.

Comment: @SamChats I have done it. Just added the PRIMARY KEY (LastName,ForeName)

Thanks didn't have much knowledge about SQL so sorry for bothering.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty Primary key works, so will a `UNIQUE` constraint.