# how to read big XML files in python without memory problem

Tags: python, pycharm, xmldataset

I am trying to read XML file "Comments.xml" which is almost 19 GB, but it gives memory error. I tried it in every IDE, but nothing works. i have 4 GB ram. i also searched, googled but did not find any clue :/
 my code is

I tried it in every IDE, but nothing works. i also searched, googled but did not find any clue :/

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='Comments.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for rows in root:
    print(rows.attrib)
```

when i run the IDE stick for some time then i get the error:
line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
MemoryError

Comment: You can't read it in as one shot, so you'll need a streaming XML parser.

Comment: streaming xml? how will i get that?

Comment: I'm not sure it will completely solve your problem but you can try the `lxml` python library which allows *iterative parsing* (so the whole tree doesn't need to be loaded in memory). See some answers of https://stackoverflow.com/q/324214/5050917 for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

i met this problem too this morning, and thankfully i found the best solution:
[The xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

to avoid taking huge memory, you can use streaming mode, here is the exmaple:

```
def handle_artist(_, artist):
    print(artist['name'])
    return True

xmltodict.parse(GzipFile('discogs_artists.xml.gz'),item_depth=2, item_callback=handle_artist)
```

Comment: I used xmltodict but gives the error " parser.Parse(xml_input, True)

ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0",  I have import xmltodict
def handle_artist(_, artist):
    print(artist['person'])
    return True
 xmltodict.parse('activity.xml',item_depth=2, item_callback=handle_artist)