# How to efficiently parse and process large XML files in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a Python program that needs to parse and process large XML files, but I'm encountering performance issues when dealing with files that are several gigabytes in size.

I'm currently using the `ElementTree` library, but it seems to be too slow for my use case. Are there more efficient ways to parse and process large XML files in Python? What libraries or techniques can I use to improve the performance of my program when dealing with such large XML files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to parse large XML docs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324214/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-parse-large-xml-docs-in-python)

Comment: Have a look to non-blocking parsers: [py doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#pull-api-for-non-blocking-parsing)

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the advertising, but another solution is to pass off the processing to a streaming implementation of XSLT 3.0, such as my company's SaxonC-EE library. This is a commercial product; it has a convenient Python API.

Any streaming approach to processing XML is going to be a bit more effort than a tree-based API because you have to think carefully about what information to retain as you stream through the document. But the advantage of using a declarative language like XSLT is that you're doing it without having to manipulate mutable state, which means that your code is much less likely to be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

If you need better performance than ElementTree you can use cElementTree.
if you are parsing large xml consider using SAX parser.
Alternatively, lxml also gives better performance.
https://lxml.de/sax.html

cElementTree's iterparse can also parse large XML incrementally.

You can also clear or remove elements that you already processed to keep memory usage low.
if you need to use Dom for some task, see if you can split the document on some child tag using a sax parser and emit that xml multiprocessing pool to parse again and use xml parser to perform your task.